# Freemarker template simulating xs:copy-of behavior

Tags: xml, freemarker

I am creating a data-model from XML content and am trying to use write a template that selects a node (containing child nodes) from the data-model.

```
final Map<String, NodeModel> root = new HashMap<String, NodeModel>();
root.put("doc", freemarker.ext.dom.NodeModel.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response))));
```

where response is:

```
<ns:Response xmlns:ns="urn:sdf.sdf.as.v1">
  <ns:MessageBody>
    <ns:Items>
      <ns:Item>
        <ns:ItemId>1</ns:ItemId>
      </Item>
      <ns:Item>
        <ns:ItemId>2</ns:ItemId>
      </Item>
    </ns:Items>
  </ns:MessageBody>
</ns:Response>
```

The template I am trying to come up with is:
    
    ${doc.Response.MessageBody.Items}

I get the following exception:

> Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression
>   doc.Response.MessageBody.Items is instead a
>   freemarker.ext.dom.NodeListModel

What am I doing wrong? Can Freemarker Template work on an Element node or does it always have to be a node value? Could it be because my template does not contain namespaces? How do I reference namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `doc.Response.MessageBody.Items.@@markup` (see: http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_formal.html)

And yes, you will have to declare XML namespaces in the template, or else you will have 0 matching nodes. See "Using XML namespaces" here: http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_imperative_learn.html#autoid_73

Comment: Is there anyway to output the nodes without namespaces.  When I use @@markup I'm getting a sequence of fully qualified elements like: <a xmlns="http://mynamespace">content</a>.  I really just want <a>content</a>.

Comment: @IanG to prevent the namespace from the input being included in the output, use @@nested_markup instead of @@markup